# need to manage private keys in windows 2003 server

Tags: windows-server-2003, permissions, iis-6, private-key

I have installed a X.509 certificate into IIS 6.0 on Windows Server 2003.
I would like to give the IIS user accesss to the certificate's private key.

I can do this on Windows 7 IIS manager very easily. How can I do this on 2003?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Run `mmc.exe`, add the Certificate Manager snap-in, and select to manage the certificates of the current computer; you'll find installed certificates in the "Personal" folder, and you will be able to export them (if they were marked as exportable in the first place).

Comment: Thanks. But what I would like to do is to grant permission to the cert's private keys to the IIS user, not export the certificate.

I discovered the following:

Install Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit Tools

Then open a Windows Server Resource Kit Tools command shell and run:

    winhttpcertcfg -g -c LOCAL_MACHINE\TrustedPeople -s SUBJECT_STRING -a IUSR_YOUR_MACHINE_HOST

where SUBJECT_STRING is a some string that identifies the certificate you have created, and IUSR_YOUR_MACHINE_HOST
is the IIS user.